# Different variations of covariant derivative product rule

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I've seen the covariant derivative product rule expressed in different forms from the standard one. For example, $$\nabla (\alpha(X)) = (\nabla \alpha)(X) + \alpha(\nabla X)$$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924940/covariant-derivative-of-covector-field/2925185#2925185). Another variation is (can't find the link to that answer, saw it a while back) $$\nabla_X(T(\omega,Y))=(\nabla_XT)(\omega,Y)+T(\nabla_X\omega,Y)+T(\omega,\nabla_X Y)$$

I'm not able to understand how these equations follow from the standard Leibniz rule for covariant derivative:
$$\nabla(T\otimes S)=\nabla T\otimes S+T\otimes\nabla S$$

I've tried thinking in terms of index notation but no luck. From my limited knowledge, $\alpha(X)$ could be called a contraction of $\alpha\otimes X$, or $T(\omega, Y)$ could be called a contraction of $T\otimes\omega\otimes Y$, but at the end of the day they're **contractions of the tensor product** and *not* the tensor product itself, which is what the standard Leibniz rule seems to be concerned with.

Comment: From a connection on $E\to M$, the induced connection on $E^*$ is required to respect the natural pairing $\Gamma(E^*\otimes E)\to C^\infty(M)$.  That is part of the definition of induced connection on bundles we construct from $E$.  Now let $E=TM$.

Comment: How is this different than your last question?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I realized it's better to ask the questions one by one rather than cram them into one post. I'll delete that one and ask those subqueries one by one so that they're not a pain to answer. **Edit**: Deleted that one.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3670732/leibniz-rule-for-covariant-derivative) answer your question?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: That's extremely helpful! I had a cursory look at it and will go into details of that question when I get back home. Thank you very much